# Is there a way to reload motion.conf without restarting the motion service?

Tags: camera, motion

I want to dynamically change on_event_start value while the motion service is running.  Is there a way to reload the motion.conf file without restarting the service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the answer from *@p4ulmac* you get the `pid` with `ps -e | grep motion`. If you like to control your services with `systemd` then there is no need to handle with the `pid`. You can simply:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reload motion.service
```

and check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status motion.service
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the following page, [Motion Guide - Getting It Running: Signals (sent with e.g. kill command)](http://lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideGettingItRunning#Signals_40sent_with_e.g._kill_command_41)

It would appear that you can send the following command;

```
kill -s SIGHUP pid
```

where pid is the pid of the motion instance you wish to update with the new config. This will refresh/reload the config to the running motion instance.